# How to test validator in jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, jquery-validate

The below is my form, where i pass in rules to validate. How to test the validate function using jasmine.

```
$("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            "name": {
                required: true,
            }
        }
});
```

I need to check whether the `validate` function returns me the right result when called?.

```
it("should return the validator object", function(){
   var form = $("#form");
   form.validate();
   expect(form).toBe /// I don't know on what to to check here?.
});
```

Can anyone guide me on what to do the next steps?.

Comment: what does `form.validate()` return? Do you just want to make sure that your function was called?

Comment: @MattBusche: form.validate() returns validator object, i need to check the function was called and also the it returned me the right thing?.

Comment: if you get back `object.isValid()` you could say `expect(object.isValid()).toBe(true)`

Comment: you can also use `spyOn()` and `toHaveBeenCalled()` and/or `toHaveBeenCalledWith()`

Comment: @MattBusche: Can you show me the example of object.isValid() relating to my example?. Is my object going to be form.isValid()

Comment: That was just an example. I don't know what your object returns, but I've given you the correct syntax.

Comment: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate this is what my validate method returns, what should  check here?.

Comment: you should dump what you're returned using `console.log()` and determine what you should verify.

Comment: console.log("Hello" +typeof $("#form").validate()); gives me just object? any other better way we can find out what we are actually getting. From the docs they say we get a type of Validator. http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Validator

Answer (score 2):

Jasime checks for values. It can do more powerful stuff with jasmine jquery (https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery). If the validator appends html to the DOM on failure you could test for that. Jamine jQuery has the tools for it (fixture, jQuery selectors, hasClass method etc.)

It may look a bit like:

```
it("should return the validator object", function(){
   var form = $("#form");
   form.validate();
   expect($('form input').toHaveClass('invalid');
});
```

Depending on your setup and coding...